# AJAX loader on page navigation - Oracle Apex 4

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am pretty new to apex development and am having trouble finding documentation on AJAX implementation. I have a few buttons that navigate to different pages. Some of these pages run very expensive sql statements and it takes a while to load. I would like to add an ajax loader just to give the user some feedback that the system is currently loading the next page.

How can I do something like this? Does Apex 4 include AJAX or do I need to load a framework such as JQuery? Any help or direction would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex 4.0 includes jQuery.  It also has a concept called [Dynamic Actions](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=34738:17:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3a%3a) that would enable you to achieve your requirement very easily.